# Pure virtual method returning const reference

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance

I have an abstract `class AbstractClass`. All my derived classes should have some `const std::vector` but... this field is associated with derived `class` (with type) - not with instances. So it could be great to have it as `static`. Of course I cannot define it in base class and I cannot force to implement this in every derived class that can be add in the future.

So I hope that somebody who will define new derived class implement it as `static`. (If not, program should works ok but there will be unnecessary memory occupation....).

So I have a pure `vitual` method returning this variable:

```
virtual const std::vector<SomeType>& getVec() const = 0;
```

My existed derived class are defined as:

```
class DerivedClass : public AbstractClass
{
public:
    const std::vector<SomeType>& getVec() const { return vec; }
private:
    static const std::vector<SomeType> Vec;
}
```

I try to do this safe and I think about possibility that other programmer will add new derived class and maybe implement it in a different way... 
For example:

```
 const std::vector<SomeType>& getVec() const { return std::vector<SomeType>{ arg1, arg2}; }
```

I defined returned type as `const reference` because I want to avoid copying (in case when `Vec` is a member of a class)... Is it ok and safe to public this method? Are there any dangers in returning `const reference`?

Comment: Returning a pointer/reference to a stack variable is a bug on its own. IMO, it has nothing to do with designing an interface.

Comment: A class is used to group together a) the data and b) the code that uses the data.   'getters' are clear evidence of design errors ... ask your self "why is the vector in these derived classes, and yet the code using the vector is somewhere else?  Alternatively, ask yourself why is the code that uses this vector not with the data?

Comment: See also, Martin Fowler's "TellDontAsk"  (in this case, tell Derived class ...)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it ok and safe to public this method?

Yes, it is.

> Are there any dangers in returning `const reference`?

No there aren't.

---

If another developer implements the interface in the way you've shown, they'll end up with undefined behavior in their code, and sooner or later it will fail.

There's no language feature preventing you from other's to use your interface and implement it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce a design by providing a different interface to inherit, with the CRTP implementing the desired behavior. You want each of your classes to have a `std::vector` static? You do the following<sup>1</sup>:

```
class AbstractClass 
{
    template<typename>
    friend class DerivedBase;

    AbstractClass() = default;

  public:
    virtual const std::vector<SomeType>& getVec() const = 0;
};

template<typename CRTP>
class DerivedBase : AbstractClass 
{
  protected:
    DerivedBase() = default;
    static const std::vector<SomeType> vec;

  public:
    const std::vector<SomeType>& getVec() const { return vec; }
};

class DerivedClass : DerivedBase<DerivedClass>
{
};
```

Now each `DerivedClass` is-a `AbstractClass` via an intermediary that enforces this design. And thanks to the CRTP, each `DerivedClass` automatically gets its own static vector.

---

<sup>[1] I omitted important details related to correctness, such as a virtual destructor, to keep the code short. Do not forget about them.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If callers of your member function play by the rules, there is absolutely no danger in making this function `public`.

A possibility that they would `const_cast` the vector, and start modifying it, exists, too. If you do not trust your users, you need to switch to copying.